# AnyLogic How to choose agent from a population with a certain probability?

Tags: random, anylogic

I have a population of agents called "destinations" made up of 14 destinations and each destination has its probability of being chosen.
At the moment I'm choosing the destination randomly by applying:

```
Destination destination = randomFrom (destinations);
```

How can I consider the probability instead of doing it randomly?

Answer (score 0):

One way: Create a table function with the cumulative probabilities as below (assuming 5 destinations 0-4, not 14):
[image]

Then, `destinations.get(tableFunction.get(uniform(0, 1)))` will return the i'th agent from the population with the right probability. So in my example, there is a 20% chance to get destination with index 0, but a 40% chance to get the one with index 2...

Comment: Convert the double to an int: "destinations.get((int)tableFunction.get(uniform(0, 1)))"

Comment: Well, test it out and play with it until it makes sense. Also, the AnyLogic help tells you about the table function and what it does. Uniform(0,1) gives you a completely random value. That is fed into the table function as an argument. Assuming you set it up with CUMULATIVE probabilities as I did, you will get an integer value out with a given chance. You take that to grab your destination by index... Play with the table function and set it up differently to see the effect. For example, only have 2 values 0&1 and set the arguments as 0 and 0.99 and see what that does. You can do it ;-)

Comment: it's better to do a step interpolation here to make the table function more intuitive in terms of the output and the conceptual cumulative probability...

Comment: Missed that, very true. Thx Felipe